# if statement check not working in ruby

Tags: ruby, string, if-statement, split

I have the following code, but when I run it, the code in the IF statement never gets executed.

I don't understand why the IF statement never gets executed despite the value of variable `c` and `key` being the same as shown in the output in bold below.

```
text = 'cab'

letters = {
  'a': 1,
  'b': 2,
  'c': 3,
}

text.split("").each do |c|
  puts c
  puts "Text #{c}"
  for key, value in letters

    puts "Key #{key}, Text #{c}, Value #{value}"
    if c == key
      puts "hello #{c}"
    end
  end
end
```

**Output**

```
c
Text c
Key a, Text c, Value 1
Key b, Text c, Value 2
Key c, Text c, Value 3
a
Text a
Key a, Text a, Value 1
Key b, Text a, Value 2
Key c, Text a, Value 3
b
Text b
Key a, Text b, Value 1
Key b, Text b, Value 2
Key c, Text b, Value 3
```

Comment: Your key is symbol, change it to string: `if c == key.to_s`

Answer (score 2):

That is because `key` is a `symbol`, not a `string`. If you wanted to use strings as keys, you would have to use the  `'a' => 1` notation instead.

Alternatively, you could call the `.to_s` method on the symbol:

`if c == key.to_s`

Comment: Thanks. What is the difference between `to_s` and `to_str` method for strings.

Comment: Basically, `to_s` is implemented for almost every object, whereas `to_str` is only for objects that are string-like. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/5682347) goes into much more detail about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your `key` is symbol, change it to string:

`if c == key.to_s`

Comment: Or he can use `=>` instead of `:` in the `letters`, so hash keys are just strings, not strings, casted into symbols.

Comment: @potashin as i know hash `key` anyway will return as symbol even if use `=>`. So he needs to convert to string.

Comment: @potashin ohh got you )) i though it `:a => 1`

Answer (score 1):

The issue that you're having is that the comparators in your `if` statement are different types, so the condition is always `false`.  Make this change:

```
letters = {
  'a' => 1,
  'b' => 2,
  'c' => 3,
}
```

This will make your `letters` hash keyed by strings, instead of symbols.  The hashrocket `=>` is used to associate a key with a value for a hash, without converting the key to a symbol.  Making the hash key a string will allow a string hash key to compare properly with a string character, which will make this work.

You could also have done an inline conversion, as suggested in other answers, like so:

```
if c == key.to_s
```

However, this will incur a *runtime penalty* each time you have to do the check.  Simply changing the hash key will make the check work, and it will mean that you don't have to manually convert one object to another each time you need to compare them.  As the `letters` hash exists solely to provide a comparison against the characters, it only makes sense to declare the keys as the type that they will be used.

This specific program isn't going to be dramatically affected by a dynamic conversion, but if you accustom yourself to spotting and avoiding unnecessary conversions, you'll improve the overall quality of your code.  Develop good coding practice early, and you'll be a much better developer in the long run.